# ArcGIS Pro set Definition Query to be between two values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, definition-query

I am using ArcGIS Pro and want to select elevation values in a polygon layer that are greater than 0 **AND** less than 1500 meters. When I right-click n layer and select Properties -> Definition query it seems I can only choose greater than or less than not a value between other values ex: 0 < x < 1500

Comment: Definition Query uses a standard SQL parser, so `elevation > 0 and elevation < 1500`. "a< b < c" is non-standard syntax. The BETWEEN operator could be used, but it's inclusive, so you'd have to change the terms: `elevation BETWEEN -1 AND 1501`

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

You just need two clauses (elevation > 0 and elevation < 1500 as @Vince commented):

[image]

Or using SQL:

[image]